# How do I remove the video lens?

Tags: unity, 12.04

How do I remove the video lens in Unity 12.04?

Answer (score 9):

Its relatively straightforward to remove the video lens.

From a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge unity-lens-video
```

Alternatively, from the software center just search for `unity-lens-video`, click remove and click *Remove All* when prompted.

Finally - logout and login.

Answer (score 6):

As it turns out, I turned the renaming lense folders into a small project that I made into a PPA.  It's located [here](https://launchpad.net/~aking1012-com/+archive/lenstoggle) if you want to try it out.  You have to log-out and log-in after you apply the changes.

It works fine for me.  Leaving the rest of the answer for historical purposes.

---

Interesting question I wondered about, but never asked.

Substitute video or any other lense name to disable other lenses.

Lenses are stored in `/usr/share/unity/lenses/`

So `cd /usr/share/unity/lenses/`.
Step in to the directory of the lense you want to disable.  I wanted to disable files `cd files`.
I renamed files.lens like so `sudo mv files.lense files.lense.ignore`
And replaced unity `unity --replace &`

Works for me with no crashes.
Before
[image: before]
After
[image]

To revert the change simply:
`sudo mv files.lense.ignore files.lense && unity --replace &`

Doing it this way is useful for just temporarily disabling a lense if you're going to take screenshots for example.  The other method is a cleaner more permanent solution.