# Keystroke error in Unity after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: unity, keyboard, 14.04

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 a strange error occurred: keystroke on <kbd>c</kbd> has no effect, whereas a longer stroke gives a lot of c's (as expected).

The error is reproducible, but appears in Unity only, not in Gnome 3.10 which is installed as well. Key <kbd>c</kbd> still works well at the login prompt. Changing the keyboard layout (from German to English) has no effect. So it shouldn't be a hardware error, nor an error of the keyboard layout. But what else could it be? As far as I mentioned, there are no other keys affected.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution:
As only Unity was affected, I came across this solution: 
[change dash lens hotkey](http://ubuntu-answers.blogspot.de/2012/05/change-dash-lens-hotkey.html)

But since lenses are scopes now, I edited file /usr/share/unity/scopes/photos.scope instead (as root): Change

```
Shortcut=c
```

to

```
Shortcut=
```

and for security, add

```
ShowEntry=false
```

Then restart Unity *and* log out or restart computer.

Additionally I removed all the lenses/scopes I never use:
[remove unity lenses](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368406/unable-to-remove-some-unity-lenses)

Do the logout/restart thing again and, voilà:
Key <kbd>c</kbd> is working again!

Answer (score 0):

After checking user275435-comment, I found a solution:
I looked through all shortcuts and disabled (press backspace) all with a hexcode, e.g. 0xa1.
Now the c-key works again.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem after upgrade to 14.04 on the unity desktop, the problem was the program touchpad-indicator. This has a shortcuts created under "All Settings - Keyboard - did own shortcuts"

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately I don't have that program installed. And "settings > keyboard > own shortcuts" is empty.