# Using Super+key that are already setup by unity

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, compiz, launcher

I want to use my <kbd>Super</kbd>key for custom shortcuts. Sometimes it does not seem possible, if the key combination is already used by Unity.

For example, I want to set <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to switch to the window demanding attention. I set it in `CCSM` -▸ `Extra WM Actions` -▸ `Activate Demanding Attention Window`, but when I press it, the launcher opens in Application mode instead. Same thing with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, it opens the Launcher in File mode instead of going fullscreen as I defined in Compiz.

I have read this article: [Can I define keyboard shortcuts using the Super key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34145/can-i-define-keyboard-shortcuts-using-the-super-key) but there is no "Key to show the launcher" in 14.04, only a "Key to show the HUD when tapped", which I have already disabled. It shows up in the `All settings` -▸ `Keyboard` as well, also disabled. As I understand, the HUD is not the same as the launcher anyway.

Ideally I would like to keep the <kbd>Super</kbd> behavior (opening launcher) when pressed alone, but still have the ability to define my own <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> combinations. I also want to keep <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>digit</kbd>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround I found is to disable the lens functionalities.

All the shortcuts I want to use are taken by lens shortcuts (`Super+a` for applications, `Super+f` for files), thus making them unusable for other functionality

I never use lenses anyway, and [removing them](https://askubuntu.com/a/419620/4246) frees the shortcuts:

```
$ dconf write /com/canonical/unity/dash/scopes "['home.scope']"
```

You can do this (and remove only some of the scopes/lenses if you wish) with dconf-editor, as per [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/485087/4246) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/372015/4246) posts.

Answer (score 1):

I set my own <kbd>Super/Win</kbd>+<kbd>SigleKey</kbd> in "System settings/Keyboard/Shorcuts":

Click the <kbd>+</kbd> on bottom to add your own shortcuts, eg mine are <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for calculator, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> ro run gnome-terminal, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to run root terminal, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to show desktop ... damned, doesn't work anymore and no option... ok found one in "unity-tweak-tool -▸ Window manager -▸ General: Keyboard shortcuts" but it doesn't work.

---

EDIT: I found in "unity-tweak-tool -▸ Launcher -▸ Additional: Keyboard shortcuts" what you search. Mine is set to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: @v2r Leon-the-cleaner, I checked google images to get the real english pathes/names in unity-tweak-tool: the roughly translated ones I referred are "Window<s>s</s> Manager-▸ General : Keyboard shortcuts" and "Launcher -▸ Additional : Keyboard shortcuts" (feel free to edit my posts and delete this one)

Comment: I only have 5mn, then the post is locked

Comment: I am able to set some shortcuts, it's only the ones that are already in use by the launcher that I can't use. `Super+f`, for example, opens the launcher in file mode. I want to override that. I would also like to keep the ability to open the launcher with a single press on `Super`.

Comment: I meet the same issue. Long `Super` won't display shortcuts list overlay, `Super+D` won't show desktop/minimize all windows, it seems like the `Super` key is disabled in some case, `Super+D` in Firefox triggers search for `d` (I have selected the Advanced option `Search when typing text`), when still in Firefox `Super+W` will correctly show the Unity `Spread windows` behaviour